# how to find the cube roots of $-27i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

i know to solve the question if it is given a+ib . but for this kind of question i can't solve it because it is only given 'ib' . for this type of question i am stuck on how to find the angle . could you help me to solve it using De Moivre's Theorem ? your help would be greatly appreciated . (=

Comment: Well, it's not true that only $ib$ is given: $ib = 0 + ib$, thus $a = 0$.

Comment: If I told you $3i$ was one of them, could you find the others from that?

Comment: You want to solve the equation $z^3=-27i=27e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}}$. You only need to use the known formula - $z^n=re^{i\theta} \Rightarrow z_k=\sqrt[n]{r}e^{i\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}} \text{ where } k=0,1,\dots,n-1$.

Answer (score 4):

You have that $\mathrm{i} = \exp(\mathrm{i} \pi / 2)$, and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

Since $-27i=(3i)^3$ it follows that $z_0=3i$ is one of such roots, by taking the another cubic roots of the unity, $\omega \neq 1\neq\omega^2$ you get the another two cubic roots: $3i\omega$ and $3i\omega^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Euler reaction, directly we have \frac13 rotation in Argand diagram..

$$ 3 ( \cos \pi/3,  \sin \pi/3), 3 ( \cos 2\pi/3,  \sin 2 \pi/3),(0,-27 i). $$